# update python modules

Tags: python, ubuntu

How can I update all python modules I have installed on ubuntu?

Comment: For ubuntu-specific questions, ask on ubuntu.stackexchange.com (and please state clearly what version of ubuntu you have, if you prefer GUI or command-line solutions, and any other relevant condition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu's repositories usually contain up-to-date versions of Python modules (prefixed with `python-`) and if you do an `apt-get dist-upgrade` will update any that you've installed from the repos.

As for packages you may have installed with `easy_install`, you could use [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) to upgrade them.

Alternatively, you can construct a list of packages you have installed with [yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk), and pass the packages in the list from `yolk -l` to `easy_install`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one click simple command to do so:

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs sudo pip install -U
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (a/k/a "easy_install"), the classic way of doing it, or [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), the new way to handle all your Python module installation needs.